# How to trigger An Action Once After NumberAnimation Is Completed In QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to call a reset function once after the animation is completed. But in the below given code , the animation starts after resetting the values

On Long press of the button I need to start an animation which basically acts as a progress bar, and once the animation is completed I need to call the reset() function.

I have tried the below given code , But here the animation starts once after the resetting of values are done.

```
Button {
    id: button1

    onPressAndHold: {
        rectangle.visible = true
        timer.restart()
    }
}

Item {
    id: rectangle

    Behavior on width {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 1000
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
        }
    }
    Image {
        id: img
        source: "somesource"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
    }
}

Timer {
    id: timer
    repeat: true
    interval: 50
    onTriggered: {
        rectangle.width = img.sourceSize.width * img.progress
        if (rectangle.width <= img.sourceSize.width) {
            timer.stop()
            reset(values)
        }
    }
}
```

can you please let me know on how modify it such that the animation completes first and then the reset is done. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you probably need [Animation.finished()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-animation.html#finished-signal) signal.

Comment: I am trying to make use of the same but when I read about it , is says
**In addition, it is only emitted for top-level, standalone animations. It will not be emitted for animations in a Behavior or Transition, or animations that are part of an animation group.**

According to my use-case I am making the animation inside "Behavior on width", hence I think the finished() signal won't be emmitted

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/29857/do-stuff-after-behavior-with-animation-is-finished-in-qml) you have two options.

You can us the `onRunningChanged` handler and check if the animation is still `running`. If not call anything you want at that point.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    Behavior on width {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 1000
            onRunningChanged: {
                if (!running)
                    console.log("Animation finished")
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: rect.width = 50
    }
}
```

The other option would be to create a `SequentialAnimation` and add  a `SrcriptAction` that runs after the `NumberAnimation` is completed.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "red"

    Behavior on width {
        SequentialAnimation {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 1000 }
            ScriptAction {
                script: console.log("Animation finished")
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: rect.width = 50
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that really works for standalone Animation only that sounds a bit strange for me since the common usecase is using animations inside `Behavior` or `State`.
So you can use `NumberAnimation.onRunningChanged` or `ScriptAction` as @iam_peter said or use `Transition.onRunningChanged` as well:

```js
Window {
    height: 200
    width: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Animation test")

    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Button {
            text: "start"
            onClicked: {
                testRect.state = "state2"
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: testContainer
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Rectangle {
                id: testRect
                height: 100
                width: 0
                color: "orange"

                states: [
                    State {
                        name: "state1"
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: testRect
                            width: 0
                        }
                    },
                    State {
                        name: "state2"
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: testRect
                            width: testContainer.width
                        }
                    }
                ]
                transitions: Transition {
                    NumberAnimation {
                        property: "width"
                        duration: 2000
                        easing.type: Easing.InQuad
                    }
                    onRunningChanged: {
                        if(running == false)
                        {
                            finishRect.color = "red";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: finishRect
            Layout.preferredWidth: 100
            color: "yellow"
            width: 100
            height: width
            radius: width / 2
        }
    }
}
```